# How can I get a list of GAVs a gradle task will produce?

Tags: gradle

In a previous post, getting a (potentially complete) list of GroupID:ArtifactID:Version - GAVs - that a [maven command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095183/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-gavs-a-maven-package-command-will-produce) would produce was answered.

How could one achieve a similar list or printout (ideally file), for a gradle build?

Comment: Did you looked at the dependencies task? You can get the depencies for a given (or all) configurations:

 ./gradlew dependencies --configuration compile

Comment: Yes, that's the exact opposite of what I'm looking for.
I want a list of artifacts "gradle jar" will produce (not consume).

Comment: Ah I completly missed the topic. As far as I know there is no default mechanism to get the result. What you could do is ask a single task for it's output. To do that for all tasks just add this to your gradle file: 

`tasks.each() {task ->
    task << {
        it.outputs.getFiles().each() { resultFiles ->
            logger.lifecycle("$task.name produced: $resultFiles")
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I'm looking at `publishing` and `artifacts` - trying to see if I can find any `SoftwareComponent` objects I can print